# UINavigationController inside UIView

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I can adda UINavigationController to a UIView programmatically but how is this represented in IB?

Everytime I add UINavigationController to the view heirarchy it stays at the same level as the (root) UIView.  Is this normal?

I expected to be able to "drag" the UINavigationController underneath the View.

```
View
   - UINavigationController
   - UIView
```

but instead I get in IB:

```
View
  -UIView
UINavigationController
```

I basically have, in my app, a View that contains two sections, the top section is a UIView and the bottom section is the UINaivationController. (think of it as something like a split view but vertically)

my main question is this: Is it normal to see the UINaigationController at the same level as the root view in IB during design the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much. IB doesn't really let you do much with controller-owned views; you'll need an outlet pointing to that navigation controller, then, in `-viewDidLoad` or `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or whatever, add the navigation controller's view to whatever view you want as its parent, i.e.

```
[self.theParentViewOutlet addSubview:self.theNavigationControllerOutlet.view];
```